# "some of them" + noun vs adjective

Tags: syntax

It seems to me that the following sentence is correct:

"There were many competitors, some of them very experienced."

Is the following sentence also correct?

"He loved many songs, some of them polkas."

Comment: It's grammatical but not very idiomatic. We would say "...including some polkas" or "some of his favourite songs were polkas" (though surely a polka is a dance, not a song?).

Comment: In your example, ***some of them very experienced*** is just the shortened result after "deleting" the predictably repeated verb: *some of them **were** very experienced*. Syntactically speaking, your "polkas" example is "valid" - but idiomatically it's an unlikely thing for a native Anglophone to say (since raises but doesn't answer the question of whether he liked polkas any more or less than he liked any other kinds of "songs"). All we can say for sure is *He doesn't dislike **all** polkas*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just curious, that seems like a very substantive and conclusive comment. Why not an answer?